# CSS Layout suggestions needed

Tags: css, layout

I'm having a few list of filters. My goal is to have them display as three rows next to each other (cb1&2 / cb3&4 / cb5).

The "checkbox_container"-blocks are created automatically through the CMS. Therefore I cannot add divs in between to create columns.

I could do it by absolute positioning, but would prefer not to in case the filters change in future which would cause layout issues.

Does anyone have a clever idea how to achieve this with CSS and/or JS?

That's the basic structure of the checkbox container output by the CMS.

```
<div class="checkboxes">
  <div class="checkbox_container cb01">
    <div class="entry"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container cb02">
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container cb03">
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container cb04">
    <div class="entry"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container cb05">
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide a scetch of what the result should look like? Should it be 3 rows and in the first is cb01 & cb02 ? are they on top of each other? Are they next to each other? Here a small example of what you could do: https://jsfiddle.net/cnthr03z/

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/y8qywooy/3/?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @FrankProvost. Here's an example how it should look like (and how I would do it if I could set more divs). https://jsfiddle.net/gmodesignz/6bodqqm7/

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/50t7oLga/1/ , using flexbox with direction column and giving the wrapper a height to force items to wrap.

Comment: That's it @Raevenk! Does exactly what I hoped for. I was sure there's something flexbox can do for me there...

Comment: @Raevenk you should post that as answer with a little description since it seems to fit perfectly

Comment: Absolutely! @Raevenk please post as answer so I can mark it as the best solution...

Comment: Awesome, glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go jsfiddle.net/50t7oLga/1 , using flexbox with direction column and giving the wrapper a height to force items to wrap